# Depth First Search Does Not Create New Object Upon Returning

Tags: recursion, depth-first-search

The following problem is from https://leetcode.com/problems/insert-into-a-binary-search-tree/

The solution is simply to apply a depth-first search and add the new TreeNode.

The code I initially wrote was **(Case 1)**:

```
public TreeNode insertIntoBST(TreeNode root, int val) {
    if (root == null) {
        root = new TreeNode(val);
        return root;
    }

    if (val < root.val)
        insertIntoBST(root.left, val);
    else
        insertIntoBST(root.right, val);

    return root;
}
```

However, I did not get the write answer because even though the break condition creates a new TreeNode, it does show when you return the root at the end.
The answer would be the following:

Output: [4,2,7,1,3], Expected: [4,2,7,1,3,5]

Then I tried **(Case 2)**:

```
public TreeNode insertIntoBST(TreeNode root, int val) {
    if (root == null) {
        return new TreeNode(val);
    }
    if (val > root.val) {
        root.right = insertIntoBST(root.right, val);
    } else {
        root.left = insertIntoBST(root.left, val);
    }
    return root;
}
```

And I got the correct answer. I understand that the correct answer here is due to the "root.left" in the if/else condition, but in Case 1, it would recursively take me to root.left and then create a new TreeNode for the variable root and return it.

What is the logic behind Case 1 not working?
Recursion really boggles my mind sometimes.

Comment: This isn't a DFS, it's a binary search. The first version makes no assignments, so how is the new node supposed to be added to the tree? `insertIntoBST(root.left, val);` means the return value is sent to the garbage collector, while `root.right = insertIntoBST(root.right, val);` adds it to the tree as the right child of `root` (the parent node of the null entry you're replacing).

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you! I thought when we write `insertIntoBST(root.left, val);`, we are in the root.left node, so if can just write `root = new TreeNode(val);`, it will add it to that position. Isn't that an assignment?

Comment: I see the confusion. That overwrites a local variable `root` that was previously null and isn't attached to anything. If there's no `.left = ...` or `.right = ...` assignment on an object somewhere, the tree won't be mutated.